# Using Node on Network Server

Tags: node.js, git, bash

How does node work? I have installed node on the server. On the same network is my work computer where I have git bash and my project files. Am i unable to run my files on my work computer as long as I call the right port number? I am running the code below on my local machine calling the ip address and port number. But then I am getting this error. `Error 0x2 starting node.exe index.js`

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!n');
}).listen(1337, 'ip');
console.log('Server running at http://ip:1337/');
```

Comment: Which server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is due to a corrupted binary, I would reinstall both git and node to fix problem.

Comment: Server PC; it's where the repository is.

Comment: its only supposed to be on the server pc? how do u call your work then? you have to always open up the server?

Comment: my only question is that u must always be logged into the server to use it then?